# How do I exclude something from showing up with FindStr?

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I need to find multiple strings but the strings I look up flag for being in the batch itself. I search the string Incognito and the batch including it flags. How do I prevent this?

---

Edit: This is a snippet of my current code. Basically it opens the text file and shows this batch file in it and other stuff too which is good, but I need it not to flag this batch file.

```
findstr /i /s /m "Obligatory" *.* > str-unfixed.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
Call :TypeWriter "Obligatory Strings Found."
) else (
Call :TypeWriter "No Obligatory Strings Found."
)
start "" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\str-unfixed.txt"
```

Don't worry about the TypeWriter, this is only a snippet.

---

Edit2: Thanks for the edit Mofi, but it blanks out at console and doesn't complete. 
Full script. Here we go.

```
@echo off
goto Next
::*************************************************************
:TypeWriter
echo(
(
echo strText=wscript.arguments(0^)
echo intTextLen = Len(strText^)
echo intPause = 30
echo For x = 1 to intTextLen
echo     strTempText = Mid(strText,x,1^)
echo     WScript.StdOut.Write strTempText
echo     WScript.Sleep intPause
echo Next
)>%tmp%\%~n0.vbs
@cscript.EXE /noLogo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" "%~1"
echo(
exit /b
::**************************************************************
:Next
@echo off
set "OutputFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\str-unfixed.txt"
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /i /s /m "Vape" *.* | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /L /V /C:"%~nx0" >"%OutputFile%"
for %%I in ("%OutputFile%") do if %%~zI == 0 goto VapeNoFileFound
for %%I in ("%OutputFile%") do if %%~zI == 1 goto VapeFileFound
:VapeFileFound
Call :TypeWriter "Vape Strings Found."
goto Kurium
:VapeNoFileFound
Call :TypeWriter "No Vape Strings Found."
goto Kurium

:Kurium
set "OutputFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\str-unfixed.txt"
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /i /s /m "Kurium" *.* | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /L /V /C:"%~nx0" >>"%OutputFile%"
for %%I in ("%OutputFile%") do if %%~zI == 0 goto KuriumNoFileFound
for %%I in ("%OutputFile%") do if %%~zI == 1 goto KuriumFileFound
:KuriumFileFound
Call :TypeWriter "Kurium Strings Found."
goto Spook
:KuriumNoFileFound
Call :TypeWriter "No Kurium Strings Found."
goto Spook

:Spook
set "OutputFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\str-unfixed.txt"
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /i /s /m "Spook" *.* | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /L /V /C:"%~nx0" >>"%OutputFile%"
for %%I in ("%OutputFile%") do if %%~zI == 0 goto SpookNoFileFound
for %%I in ("%OutputFile%") do if %%~zI == 1 goto SpookFileFound
:SpookFileFound
Call :TypeWriter "Spook Strings Found."
goto Aimassist
:SpookNoFileFound
Call :TypeWriter "No Spook Strings Found."
goto Aimassist

:Aimassist
set "OutputFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\str-unfixed.txt"
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /i /s /m "Aimassist" *.* | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /L /V /C:"%~nx0" >>"%OutputFile%"
for %%I in ("%OutputFile%") do if %%~zI == 0 goto AANoFileFound
for %%I in ("%OutputFile%") do if %%~zI == 1 goto AAFileFound
:AAFileFound
Call :TypeWriter "Aim Assist Strings Found."
goto Triggerbot
:AANoFileFound
Call :TypeWriter "No Aim Assist Strings Found."
goto Triggerbot

:Triggerbot
set "OutputFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\str-unfixed.txt"
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /i /s /m "Triggerbot" *.* | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /L /V /C:"%~nx0" >>"%OutputFile%"
for %%I in ("%OutputFile%") do if %%~zI == 0 goto TRNoFileFound
for %%I in ("%OutputFile%") do if %%~zI == 1 goto TRFileFound
cscript //nologo "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\dedup.vbs" < "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\str-unfixed.txt" > "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\str-fixed.txt"
del /s /q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\str-unfixed.txt" > nul
:TRFileFound
Call :TypeWriter "Triggerbot Strings Found."
start "" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\str-fixed.txt"
:TRNoFileFound
Call :TypeWriter "No Triggerbot Strings Found."
start "" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\str-fixed.txt"

pause > nul
::************************************************
```

And if you need dedup.vbs:

```
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    On Error Resume Next
    Line=Inp.readline
    Dict.Add Line, ""
Loop
For Each thing in Dict.Keys()
    Outp.writeline thing
Next
```

---

Edit3: Thanks Mofi!

My problem: need to get the items in the text document to show up on cmd window.

Script:

```
@echo off
goto Next
::*************************************************************
:TypeWriter
echo(
(
echo strText=wscript.arguments(0^)
echo intTextLen = Len(strText^)
echo intPause = 30
echo For x = 1 to intTextLen
echo     strTempText = Mid(strText,x,1^)
echo     WScript.StdOut.Write strTempText
echo     WScript.Sleep intPause
echo Next
)>%tmp%\%~n0.vbs
@cscript.EXE /noLogo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" "%~1"
echo(
exit /b
::**************************************************************
:Next
@echo off
findstr /i /s /m /C:"Vape" /C:"Kurium" /C:"Spook" /C:"Aimassist" /C:"Triggerbot" /C:"Smoothaim" *.* > str-unfixed.txt
cscript //nologo "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\dedup.vbs" < "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\str-unfixed.txt" > "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\str-fixed.txt"
if %errorlevel%==0 (
Call :TypeWriter "Blacklisted Strings Found."
start "" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\str-fixed.txt"
) else (
Call :TypeWriter "No Blacklisted Strings Found."
start "" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\str-fixed.txt"
)
pause > nul
::************************************************
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.  Please post your current code and a clear problem statement.  See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what do you mean by "flag for being in the batch itself". Show what's the output and what you expected

Comment: It seems like you're trying to scan the directory containing the batch file, but exclude the batch file itself.  The easiest way to do that is to put the batch into a different directory.

Comment: Ryan, I'm scanning the entire C:\ drive.

Comment: Name I can't pronounce, it lists other stuff like vsq.dll and other txts and jars, along with the ok.bat file (what i named it) which i dont want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch file could be filtered out for example with using this code:

```
@echo off
set "OutputFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\str-unfixed.txt"
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /M /S "Obligatory" *.* | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /L /V /C:"%~nx0" >"%OutputFile%"
for %%I in ("%OutputFile%") do if %%~zI == 0 goto NoFileFound

call :TypeWriter "Obligatory strings found."
start "" "%OutputFile%"
set "OutputFile="
goto :EOF

:NoFileFound
del "%OutputFile%"
set "OutputFile="
call :TypeWriter "No obligatory string found."
goto :EOF

:TypeWriter
echo %~1
```

The output of first **FINDSTR** is filtered with a second **FINDSTR** which outputs all lines not ending with the name of the batch file searched as case-sensitive literal string.

The **FOR** command is used to check the file size of the output file.

Is the output file an empty file, i.e. the file size is equal 0 bytes, the string `Obligatory` was not found in any file except the batch file itself resulting in deleting the output file and printing the appropriate message.

Otherwise after printing the message that the string was found, the output file is opened in the application associated with file extension .txt.

The batch file above was tested for both scenarios on a subdirectory and not on entire drive C: as it can take a quite long time to finish on C:. There are hundred thousands of files on drive C: with dozens of GiB in total to search for the string when using `*.*` as file name pattern and start in root of drive C:.

---

**EDIT 1: Define string to find in two parts**

A much better solution as above is avoiding search string being in batch file. This can be done by using an environment variable for the string to find and define the value of the environment variable in two steps.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "OutputFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\str-unfixed.txt"

set "StringToFind=Obli"
set "StringToFind=%StringToFind%gatory"

%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /M /S "%StringToFind%" *.* >"%OutputFile%"

if errorlevel 1 (
    del "%OutputFile%"
    call :TypeWriter "No %StringToFind% strings found."
) else (
    call :TypeWriter "%StringToFind% strings found."
    start "" "%OutputFile%"
)

endlocal
goto :EOF

:TypeWriter
echo %~1
```

This batch file also searches for `Obligatory`, but it does not contain this string, just `Obli` and `gatory`.

---

**EDIT 2: Define strings to find with omitted escape character**

Here is one more solution where the multiple strings to find are assigned to environment variables with escape character `^` anywhere in the middle of the search strings to exclude the batch file.

`^` is removed by Windows command interpreter on assigning the search strings to the environment variables as not being found within a double quoted string. Please note that this solution requires that the lines

```
set SearchX=S^earch String
```

do not have 1 or more trailing spaces/tabs as the trailing whitespace(s) would be also assigned to the environment variable. The search would not work anymore as expected with a not visible space or horizontal tab at end of those lines as being part of the search string.

Additionally this batch code outputs first each file name found by **FINDSTR** containing one of the 6 search strings to console window and next redirects the file name into the output text file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "OutputFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\str-unfixed.txt"

rem Define all search strings with omitted escape character.
set Search1=V^ape
set Search2=K^urium
set Search3=S^pook
set Search4=A^imassist
set Search5=T^riggerbot
set Search6=S^moothaim

rem Delete the output file from a previous run if existing at all.
del "%OutputFile%" 2>nul

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /M /S /C:"%Search1%" /C:"%Search2%" /C:"%Search3%" /C:"%Search4%" /C:"%Search5%" /C:"%Search6%" *') do (
    echo %%I
    echo %%I>>"%OutputFile%"
)

if exist "%OutputFile%" (
    call :TypeWriter "Obligatory strings found."
    start "" "%OutputFile%"
) else (
    call :TypeWriter "No obligatory string found."
)
endlocal
goto :EOF

:TypeWriter
echo %~1
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`

See also the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576) and Microsoft TechNet article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe the results through another check for the script name.

Replace your first line, `findstr /i /s /m "Obligatory" *.* > str-unfixed.txt` with this:

```dos
findstr/ism "Obligatory" *.*|findstr/ixvc:"%~nx0">str-unfixed.txt
```

I will add however that I would strongly suggest not searching through every single file on the C: drive looking for a specific search term. You really do need to filter this somehow perhaps by altering your file wildcard/mask.